# How to generate Identicon in Delphi

Tags: delphi, using, identicon

I've been given the task to implement [`Identicon`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) using Delphi. I have searched the internet and still did not find anything. 
so where do I begin, is there someone here who can give an explanation?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/gravatars-identicons-and-you/

Comment: There are many many pages discussing them if you do a websearch. Something tells me that what you really want is some code.

Comment: And LURD's link to the wikipedia page contains links to source code. It really looks to me like you should try harder.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Well of course I've visited that link before. but there's none of samples code from Delphi. I need a more detailed explanation. My plan is to create routine to generate identicon.

Comment: In other words you were asking for code. You should have said so.

Answer (score 21):

This is just an **explanation** to give you the **idea** of the Identicons.

Identicons are graphical representations of a bunch of bytes most likely a hash value.

Lets take a sample MD5 hash value (16 bytes)

```
abf5787309f3c4d5b255237c0b67dd5e
```

Ok let them arrange in a different way

```
ab f5 78 73
09 f3 c4 d5
b2 55 23 7c
0b 67 dd 5e
```

Now we have 16 fields each representing a byte. So we could build an image with 256 different small images. But maybe we can break it down to a less complicated method.

Lets take one byte (the first one *ab*) and its binary representation

```
10101011
```

Ok, let them arrange in a different way :o)

```
10 10
10 11
```

Now we have 4 fields and each field can have one of four states. And that is very easy to manage 4 different images.

```
00 = empty
01 = /
10 = \
11 = X
```

Back to our byte we will get this

```
┌─────┐
│ \ \ │
│ \ X │
└─────┘
```

And back to the whole we get

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ \ \ │ X X │ / X │ / X │
│ \ X │ / / │ \   │   X │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│     │   X │ X   │ X / │
│ \ / │ X   │ /   │ / / │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│ \ X │ / / │   \ │ / X │
│   \ │ / / │   X │ X   │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│     │ / \ │ X / │ / / │
│ \ X │ / X │ X / │ X \ │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

The whole point here is reduction into easy to handle small parts.

Answer (score 1):

I once started to port the original library to Delphi / Graphics32. However, I never found the time to finish the small project until now. The source code together with a sample application can be found on [my website (see Delphi -> Graphics32)](http://www.savioursofsoul.de/Christian/delphi/graphics32/#identicon).

Originally it was meant to show some new vector graphic features from the upcoming version 2.0. Despite the fact, that this has still not been released, the source code can already be compiled with the code in the trunk repository.